# Who decides, and how, that a feature request or bug will not be implemented or fixed at the present time?

Tags: discussion, meta, bug-reporting-process, feature-request-process

You can find the most voted "status-declined" questions on the following list.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined

Where it says that the tag

> indicates that the feature request or bug will not be implemented or fixed at the present time.

If you look at the list, there are highly up-voted questions. Lots of upvotes means the community likes that feature.

So who decides "the feature request or bug will not be implemented or fixed at the present time"? And how do they decide?

Comment: The Stack Exchange team (headed by a product manager) based on what will improve or add to their business value.

Comment: You could easily have checked who added the `status-` tag to the posts, and see what answers are there. Please do some research first.

Comment: This is all smoke and mirrors to deflect from the fact that *I* single-handedly make those decisions. In completely unrelated news, I have an Amazon wishlist.

Comment: voting up. Usually I vote questions down for the lack of effort but this case is special as lack of effort demonstrated by SE team in addressing needs of site community looks so blatant (making it natural to wonder if they do anything for community at all, even after seeing all the previous posts on this matter)

Comment: @gnat Please look at all the data. 390 [status-declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) vs. 2418 [status-completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: @BilltheLizard please give an example that had impact on the experience of core community at Stack Overflow. Such as eg changing default background in historically locked posts (which would help preventing inappropriate questions with millions views from being wide open [broken windows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info) for outside readers)

Comment: @gnat The notice on [historically locked posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929/hidden-features-of-asp-net) was moved to the top of the post. I don't think people are missing it. Also, how many historically locked posts are there? (My [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3A1+historical+significance) only turned up two, but that can't be right.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard it's not about how many questions but how many views on these. [15 millions views at Stack Overflow, I counted already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285985/165773). And no, notice on top won't help (it's not much prominent even to me, a long-time user, not to mention total strangers who make these millions views)

Comment: @gnat You posted your feature request for that on Software Engineering Meta, where it's only been viewed 177 times. Will's post on Meta SE is tagged discussion. Maybe post that as a full feature request on here or Meta SE to get some attention for it?

Comment: @BilltheLizard have you read instructions in the request for proposals where it was posted? "So what do you think we should include in this round? Try to link to the feature-request, but don't fret too much if you can't find it (just explain what it wanted, and we can rely on Shog9's RAM-like memory for the location)"

Comment: @gnat Yes, I read that. How is that working so far?

Comment: not working at all @BilltheLizard (just in case if you think that absence of feature request may relate, no, it doesn't help either: [proposal for notice of possible duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285952/165773) is ignored exactly the same, despite presence of highly viewed and voted request)

Comment: @gnat I have similar concerns but the response is clear here: PM makes all the decisions. So unless SO plans to change that policy there's no point arguing with the random unrelated people here who don't have a clue or a say. META is a weird place where the moderators and site owners seem to downvote criticism and upvote feel good stuffs but that's another story for another day (and another post that will be downvoted).

Comment: Whatever happened to assuming good intentions?

Answer (score 9):

[Pekka makes all of these decisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363316/who-decides-and-how-that-a-feature-request-or-bug-will-not-be-implemented-or-f#comment557322_363316), and is compensated in the form of a [discount Gucci handbag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUpgr.png) stuffed full of stickers whenever he indicates that he wants another one. ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26518/50049))

The above is the honest truth, but I'm going to give you something a *little* closer to the answer that you were probably looking for.

***There's not really a single decision maker***, though all of our products do have (ultimately) a single owner and end of accountability chain - the product manager. I can give you a rough outline of how the process doesn't work, because as I said, it's really only Pekka, but:

- A feature is requested and seen by a community manager, developer, PM and there are *compelling* reasons to not implement the feature -> it's probably going to be declined rather quickly.
- A feature is requested and seen (as above) and looks like it might be worth investigating -> it's probably going to get deferred until we have the time to look into it, or some other work is completed that might be blocking it, etc.
- A feature is requested that we've already got in mind, or immediately decide that we're *going* to do (similar to above) - it's probably going to be marked as planned.

***We don't do a very good job of indicating presence on feature requests*** (as in, yes, we saw it, and here's our initial / immediate thoughts), but this is something we're actively working on getting better at doing, and probably entails 'meta' sites being a bit more of a departure in terms of functionality from the parent Q&A site.

Each team has a subset of things they want to work on to help meet specific goals, they prioritize that list, the PM ultimately prioritizes all the lists and decides what needs to happen next. It's the PMs job to balance use and business cases, what's going to make the most impact, etc.

Ultimately, it's <strike>Pekka's</strike> the PMs call, but our PMs generally do a great job of taking input from other teams that are close to the larger variety of use cases that we see every day.

But I'll leave it up to <strike>an actual PM</strike> Pekka to chime in with more info if needed.

Comment: Psh.  Gucci bags are way too expensive.  All I want are hoodies.  Stickers can be places in the pockets.  For the price of one Pekka decision you could have twenty Makoto decisions. :)

Comment: In all seriousness, I feel like we've had this conversation before - somewhere on Meta Stack Exchange.  There was quite a discussion about how communication needs to improve.  This was easily a year ago.  It's definitely known that we need to see what is moving and how it's moving, but communicating that in a way that we feel is good is...well...tough.  Most of the efforts being done that desire communication - like a few of the ad and other efforts - have not been met warmly...

Comment: @Makoto It started breaking when we started growing and more people became part of the decision making process, and more people end up shaping what we ultimately ship (which could, very easily, become something quite distant from what was originally discussed) and as each person gets involved there's probably 3 - 4 opportunities to communicate that inevitably get overlooked. Even with a very conscious effort to get better at communicating, meta sites just don't scale so well; We're looking at how to better manage presence on stuff right now. A survey is going out soon to help that.

Comment: @Makoto [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange)?  ... [status-declined]

Comment: @rene:  Looks familiar, but I'm certain I'd have voted on at least one of the answers.

Comment: @TimPost I think the most frustration comes from the literally hundreds (several hundred by now) feature requests who are upvoted, get a bunch of positive response from the community and then just die off, never to be seen or responded to by SE staff. Then when inevitably someone has the same idea a year later, theirs gets closed as duplicate of the first one and it still ends up ignored and sinks back into obscurity. It'd help to have at least 1 SE employee respond to every feature request

Comment: @TimPost 'It started breaking when we started growing' for some reason' I read that as 'growling'.  Maybe it's the font...